# Unable to compile code despite setting the target Platform

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, target-platform

I am unable to compile my code despite setting the target platform containing all the required jars. I tried cleaning my workspace and restarting eclipse but it didn't help.

When i include that folder (which contains all the jars) in the build path, it compiles fine.

Kindly help!

Comment: Can you see the markers view? It will show the exact problem in compilation.

Comment: It should work. What problems are you facing? Also check active target platform in the preference page. Is Target platform is remote one or local? Add more details to the question

Comment: Are the jars in the target platform plugins? The target platform is only for plugins.